# Continuity of intersection points of projective algebraic varieties

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry

Suppose that $X \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ is a (possibly singular) algebraic curve. Let $H_{\tau} \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ be a family of hyperplanes, with $\tau \in (-1,1)$.

By Bezout's theorem, the count of intersection points (with multiplicity) is independent of $\tau$.   (Let us assume that $H_{\tau}$ does not contain any irreducible components of $X$, and that $X$ is reduced. This justifies the application of Bezout's theorem).

Question: I would like to say that the intersection points vary continuously in $\mathbb{CP}^n$, with respect to the Euclidean topology. Is this statement true, and if so, where can it be found in the literature?

Comment: what is the role of $\tau$ here? You might need some kind of "generic" requirement. As in, take two lines through the origin, and some angle $\tau$ parametrizing their slope in $\mathbb CP^{1}$. Fixing one $H_0$, we can see that no matter what happens, as $\tau$ passes through this, there will be infinitely many intersections when they are the same line. The same issue arises in higher dimensions, although they need not be the same hyperplane, right?

Comment: Of course, are you saying euclidian topology on $(-1,1)$?

Comment: @AndresMejia I am indeed using the Euclidean topology. Regarding the "genericity assumption", I agree with you that one ought to add more hypotheses.  I will update the question to reflect this. Thanks!